# I mean a user ID can't be auth in two different machines at the same time. How can I control this? I'm using the SQUID with Apache server platform.?

Tags: linux, operating-system, centos

I mean a user ID can't be auth in two different machines at the same time. How can I control this? I'm using the SQUID with Apache platform.?

Answer (score 0):

If the user database table (say it is called UserTable) is only on one machine, then add a field in that table called "CurrentMachine" and give the field a default value of '' (empty string).

When a user with UserID 'Tom' successfully logs in to a machine named 'ServerA' then send this query:

UPDATE UserTable SET CurrentMachine='ServerA' WHERE UserID='Tom';

Whenever a user logs out OR his/her session expires (use the session end event) send this query

UPDATE UserTable SET CurrentMachine='' WHERE UserID='Tom';

In order to test that a user is not logging in to multiple machines use this query when they attempt to log in:

SELECT CurrentMachine FROM UserTable WHERE UserID='Tom'

If the value returned is '' (empty string) then let them log in and run the first query above so that they can't log in anywhere else until they log out or their session expires. If the value returned is the name of another machine, don't let them log in.

NOTE: I used a text ID for clarity. The SQUID is the same, just a longer string.